# Ubuntu guest os with dual network interfaces resetting resolv.conf

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vmware-workstation

I have an Ubuntu 10.10 guest os on VMWare workstation with two network interfaces.  One of the interfaces is bridged with the physical interface and uses dhcp.  The other is host-only and uses a static IP.  I have set up /etc/interfaces to look like this:

```
//lo def here

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.79.128
gateway 192.168.79.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

and /etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 192.168.3.5
nameserver 192.168.3.50
domain host.com
search host.com
```

Now it works for a little while and then dhclient (i think) overwrites resolv.conf and sets a single nameserver, 192.168.79.1.  I've killed nm-applet, so I know it's not that POS getting in the way.  I've also tried editing /etc/dhcp3/dhclient.conf, but to no avail:

```
supersede domain-name-servers 192.168.3.5,192.168.3.50
```

I've done some googling, but have found no viable solutions.  Has anyone come up with a solution to this issue?

Comment: Hi its network manager that is rewriting your resolv.conf. If you can live without network manager then I'd suggest to remove it, although there are a number of ways to get round it one is to make resolv.conf read only (after editing) although im sure there are much better ways to do it so ill leave this is comment.

Comment: I killed the nm-applet process using kill -9 instead of gracefully stopping the process with service.  Perhaps there was another process associated with network-manager changing it.  Testing right now, will keep you updated.

Comment: You need to run sudo stop network-manager I think not a 100% that nm-applet is just part of the GUI frontend so killing that may not kill the part rewriting ur resolv.conf, you can try killall networkmanager.

Comment: Thanks, completely removing network-manager solved my problem.  Also, chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf works, but I prefer to discard network manager altogether.  Also, I need to remove the default gateway for the host-only interface.  Post your solution under answers, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi its network manager that is rewriting your resolv.conf. If you can live without network manager then I'd suggest to remove it, another way would be to make resolv.conf read only (after editing)